# How can I toggle between Fn and function F-keys on Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook

I've found this annoying problem where if I press function keys they don't perform as expected. <kbd>F12</kbd> opens up Chrome's inspector while <kbd>F11</kbd> just hides windows to show the desktop.

The only way I can click to, say, change brightness is to click the <kbd>FN</kbd> key.

What is causing this and how do I change it back to standard function key functionality? And what causes it in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Function keys as standard key in one app only?](https://superuser.com/questions/49209/how-to-use-function-keys-as-standard-key-in-one-app-only)

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke - it's not a great dupe match, though I'm surprised I can't find a better one at the moment. I'll drop in an answer & if we find a good one later we can always close it against that.

Comment: Yes, I see that it's not a very good match. I referenced that question as it also refers to a question over at Apple.SE, but the answer [on this question](https://superuser.com/q/1434/141595) is maybe a better fit?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke - all useful, but tbh, I think it might be OK to leave this one as a standalone 'how do i switch it over, just the once?'. Simple Q, simple A. the others have now populated the sidebar, for deeper interest. I guess we'll have to see what others think. [I'm easy either way, really:)

Comment: I'm using Monterey and it just keeps switching. Can't find the option to switch back to normal functionality System Settings for me has caused all sorts of trouble.

Comment: Oops,  changed to Ventura. My stupidity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set which way this behaves in System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard
'Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys'

[image]

Whichever way you choose, holding Fn/F-key will activate the opposite mode temporarily.

This pref pane has changed appearance slightly over the years, but the functionality remains the same up to Monterey, but it has moved in Ventura.

1. Go to keyboard shortcuts
   [image: List item]
2. Go to the function keys tab and turn on "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys".
   [image]

from [Apple KB](https://support.apple.com/HT204436)

> macOS Ventura
> Choose Apple menu  > System Settings.
> Click Keyboard in the sidebar.
> Click the Keyboard Shortcuts button on the right.
> Click Function Keys in the sidebar.
> Turn on "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys".

Comment: I'm using Monterey and that doesn't appear under System Settings > keyboard.

Comment: It's in just the same place on Monterey - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KArk1.png Ventura may have changed things, but I don't have that yet on any of the Macs here.

Comment: Answer updated with Ventura changes

Comment: Once I worked it, it worked. Well done done Sir.

Comment: Apple says "*If you don't see this setting, you might be using a keyboard not made by Apple*". They key word there is **might**. I am using a keyboard made by Apple - specifically model A1243 but the setting does not show up. How stupid. Worked fine before Sonoma.

Answer (score 7):

On a [Macally](https://appleinsider.com/articles/23/06/23/macally-bluetooth-keyboard-review-great-keyboard-with-an-underwhelming-trackpad) keyboard, I've found that holding <kbd>Fn</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will "lock" the Fn key allowing me to use the function keys by default.  Without this, even having set the "Use F1, F2 keys etc..." it wasn't working without holding the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. Locking it worked like a charm.

Comment: Yeah I too observed. Why is MacOS not changing the keys with the option toggled? I had to hold fn key to see change in keys.

Answer (score 0):

##### [macOS v13.3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura) (Chrome)

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

The above command will toggle the taskbar. Coming from a Windows OS, this was the combination I was looking for to mimic: <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

As well as enabling the "Use F1, F2, etc" option, you may also want to un-bind the F11 key from the "Show Desktop" feature.

[image: Show desktop keyboard shortcut]